# Unable to Apply CSS style to SVG text element

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, svg

I noticed that when you append text with JS, some styling rules work and others cease to work. To be specific, consider my css style rule that creates a `border-bottom` on hover...

```js
var svg = d3.select('body')
        .append('svg')
        .attr('height',200)
        .attr('width',200);

svg.append('a')
    .append('text')
    .html('This is not a text.')
    .attr('font-size', '14px')
    .attr('class', 'content-text-1')
    .attr('x', 10)
    .attr('y', 20);
```

```css
.content-text-1:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<body>
</body>
```

I don't believe this a "asynchronous" type of issue, because when I create other things, such as, svg `rects` or `circles` (just to name a few), they can be styled after the fact.

**Question:** What is causing the `border-bottom` not to show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is not the CSS, but the SVG instead. SVG does not support `border-bottom` property.

For instance, you can clearly see that the CSS works if you have HTML elements:

```js
var div = d3.select('body')
  .append('div')
  .html('This is not a text.')
  .style('font-size', '14px')
  .attr('class', 'content-text-1');
```

```css
.content-text-1:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Give `div` instead of `svg` beacause `svg` have its unique identity it's not supported `border-bottom`.

```js
var div = d3.select('body')
        .append('div')
        .attr('height',200)
        .attr('width',200);

div.append('a')
    .append('text')
    .html('This is not a text.')
    .attr('font-size', '14px')
    .attr('class', 'content-text-1')
    .attr('x', 10)
    .attr('y', 20);
```

```css
.content-text-1:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<body>
</body>
```

Comment: hmmm, wow, why does the variable name make so much of a difference? Is `svg` a glitchy reserved name or something?

Comment: @ArashHowaida It has absolutely nothing to do with the variable name. The answerer here is appending a `div`, which is a HTML element.

Comment: Yes svg is different thing. SVG is an XML-based vector image format for two-dimensional graphics with support for interactivity and animation. For more information you can see https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_intro.asp